# how to make a class accept a method without specifying the method in advance?

Tags: javascript, methods

If i have something like this :

```
function foo(class){
    for(i=0; i<(class.length);i++){
       return document.getElementsByClassName(class)[i];
    }
}
```

And now i want to do something like this:

```
 foo("someclass").innerHTML="something";
```

it will do it only for the first element and i understand why this happens and how to make it work correctly, but how can i make the function get other methods without telling it in the loop exactly what to do,like this

```
   foo("someclass").innerHTML="something";//this to put something inside the element
   foo("someclass").style.backgroundColor="#000");// and this to work also
```

So,if its possible,how can i make the function do this without putting these methods in the foo function loop? Is there a way to put these methods in a variable like this

```
  function foo(class).variableMethod{
for(i=0; i<(class.length);i++){
   document.getElementsByClassName(class)[i].variableMethod;
}
```

}

Is this possible?

Comment: so do you want to apply the same `innerHTML` (or anything) to every element with a particular class?

Comment: yes, but also if sometimes i need to change the style, i want it to change the style without me having to make another fucntion like foo that will have inside the for loop someclass[i].style

Comment: Petre, please see my updated answer below. This may answer your question abour one way jQuery can do similar things to what you're trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a function to `foo()`, and have `foo()` call that function with each matched element:

```
function foo(className, func)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        func(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
foo("someclass", function(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "something";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other great answers here, one thing you could do is create on override method called `innerHtml`. You could then have innerHtml check for a collection as well as a single instance and opperate as required.

**UPDATE**

Here's a quick example of method chaining. Here I basically obtain a collection of elements based on tag name and set their value using a val() method that I created using the Javascript `prototype` object.

```
function Foo(tagName)
{
    this.collection = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    return this;
}

Foo.prototype.val= function(value){

   for(var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++)
   {
       this.collection[i].innerHTML = value;
   }
}


var x = new Foo("li").val("Hello World");
```

You can see a working demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/E48ym/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Frédéric Hamidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774063/how-to-make-a-class-accept-a-method-without-specifying-the-method-in-advance/6774152#6774152) will do what you want I think, but you could also use a framework like jQuery - this is the kind of thing it was designed for. So you could do:

```
$('.className').text('something');
```

to set the text of all elements with a class of `className` to *something*, or

```
$('.className').css('background-color', '#000');
```

to change the background color of all elements with a class of `className`.

Comment: i know that i can use jquery, but im trying to figure out how jquery is doing this, because jquery takes the some elements with a class and then it works with many methods like .text or .css

Comment: You could always take a look at the jQuery code to see that, right?

Comment: i tried but i dont understand, i cant find the part im looking for

Comment: @Petre: ok, fair enough. You could also look at Paul Irish's *10 things I learned from the jQuery source* (http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source), and Jon Resig's *Learning Advanced Javascript* (http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)